# Error in Attaching Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting this error when I am trying item from a model collection in Entity framework. I get the following error:

> Attaching an entity of type '' failed because another entity of the
>   same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when
>   using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate

Please can someone help out am stuck
here is my code:

```
 public class Attendees 
 {
    [Key]
    public int AttendeesId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Programme> programmes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Presentations> presentations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Abstracts> abstracts { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsKeynoteSpeaker { get; set; }



  }
public class Programme
{
    [Key]
    public int ProgrammeId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(256,
        ErrorMessage = "The length of the field is more than expected")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attendees> presenters { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attendees> chairpersons { get; set; }
    public ProgrammeType programmeType { get; set; }
    public ConferenceDay Daynumber { get; set; }


}

public void RemovePresenterFromProgramme(Programme programme,Attendees        attendees)
    {
        var context = _programmeRepository.GetGenericRepository.GetDbContext as ConferenceDbContext;

        context.Entry(programme).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; // get the error here
        var attendee = programme.presenters
            .Where(c => c.AttendeesId == attendees.AttendeesId).SingleOrDefault();

        programme.presenters.Remove(attendee);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Junnas, for help but i found away around this. The error was thrown because the Programme object had a navigation property that already existed within the context. This was causing it not to attach, so this what i did to fix it.

```
var context = _programmeRepository.GetGenericRepository.GetDbContext as ConferenceDbContext;
context.Entry(attendees).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
context.ProgrammeObjects.Attach(programme);
var attendee = programme.presenters
            .Where(c => c.AttendeesId ==    attendees.AttendeesId).SingleOrDefault();
programme.presenters.Remove(attendee);

context.Entry(programme).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

context.SaveChanges();
```

The Programme object already had an attendee object that existed in the context. So had to tell entityframework to stop tracking the said attendee object by detaching it and worked for me. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try something like this ?

```
context.Programmes.Attach(programme);
 var entry = context.Entry(programme);
 entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
 var attendee = programme.presenters
            .Where(c => c.AttendeesId == attendees.AttendeesId).SingleOrDefault();

        programme.presenters.Remove(attendee);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Patel for your response. However, I applied the changes the same error was thrown in the attach code.

Comment: @user3314516, From where `( Programme programme )` has been loaded ? If `programme` has been loaded from context then dont attach it or else if it has been created outside of context then above code should work.